# apache commons LinearObjectiveFunction Algorithm

Tags: java, math, apache-commons

How does apache commons math library calculate minimum and maximum value of objective function given inequality constraint.

e.g

```
maximize 3x1+5x2 
given - 2x1+8x2<=13
5x1-x2<=11
x1>=0,x2>=0
```

what algorithm does apache commons library applies for this.

Comment: Could you give me some feedback on my answer to your question? Negative or positive feedback is very much welcome, better than no feedback at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) solver in Apache commons math.

You can solve your problem like this using this library:

```
@Test
public void testMathStackOverflow() {
    //      maximize 3x1+5x2
    //      subject to
    //          2x1+8x2<=13
    //          5x1-x2<=11
    //              x1>=0
    // x2>=0

    LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(new double[] { 3, 5}, 0);

    ArrayList<LinearConstraint> constraints = new ArrayList<>();

    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] {2, 8}, Relationship.LEQ, 13));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] {5, -1}, Relationship.LEQ, 11));

    double epsilon = 1e-6;
    SimplexSolver solver = new SimplexSolver();
    PointValuePair solution = solver.optimize(f, new LinearConstraintSet(constraints),
            GoalType.MAXIMIZE,
            new NonNegativeConstraint(true),
            PivotSelectionRule.BLAND);
    System.out.printf("x1: %f; x2: %f; max: %f", solution.getPoint()[0], solution.getPoint()[1], solution.getValue());
}
```

The result is:

```
x1: 2.404762; x2: 1.023810; max: 12.333333
```

I have used these dependencies:

```
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-math4</artifactId>
<version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

For more examples of the usage of the Simplex solver in this library download the source code and check the unit tests in package:

```
org.apache.commons.math4.optim.linear
```